# Python 2.7 carriage return countdown

Tags: python, python-2.7, carriage-return, sys

I'm having trouble implementing a simple countdown in python using a carriage return.  I have two versions, each with problems.

Print Version:

```
for i in range(10):
    print "\rCountdown: %d" % i
    time.sleep(1)
```

Problem: The `\r` doesn't do anything because a newline is printed at the end, so it gives the output:

```
Countdown: 0
Countdown: 1
Countdown: 2
Countdown: 3
Countdown: 4
Countdown: 5
Countdown: 6
Countdown: 7
Countdown: 8
Countdown: 9
```

Sys.stdout.write Version:

```
for i in range(10):
    sys.stdout.write("\rCountdown: %d" % i)
    time.sleep(1)
print "\n"
```

Problem: All the sleep happens at the beginning, and after 10 seconds of sleep it just prints `Countdown: 9` to the screen.  I can see the `\r` is working behind the scenes, but how do I get the prints to be interspersed in the sleep?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For solution number 2, you need to flush stdout.

```
for i in range(10):
    sys.stdout.write("\rCountdown: %d" % i)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
print ''
```

Also, just print an empty string since print will append the newline. Or use `print '\n' ,` if you think it is more readable as the trailing comma suppresses the newline that would typically be appended.

Not sure how to fix the first one though...

Answer (score 1):

For solution 1 (the Print Version), including a comma at the end of the print statement will prevent a newline from being printed at the end, as indicated in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print). However, stdout still needs to be flushed as [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17439198/4622065) mentioned.

```
for i in range(10):
    print "\rCountdown: %d" % i,
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

An alternative is to use the [print function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print), but `sys.stdout.flush()` is still needed.

```
from __future__ import print_function
for i in range(10):
    print("\rCountdown: %d" % i, end="")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
import time
for i in range(0,10):
    print "countdown: ",10-i
    time.sleep(1)    
    print chr(12)#clear screen
print "lift off"
```

Answer (score -1):

HANDLE NONE:

> ```
> for i in xrange(10):
>     print "COUNTDOWN: %d" %i, time.sleep(1)
>
> # OP
> # Countdown: 0 None
> # Countdown: 1 None
> # Countdown: 2 None
> # Countdown: 3 None
> # Countdown: 4 None
> # Countdown: 5 None
> # Countdown: 6 None
> # Countdown: 7 None
> # Countdown: 8 None
> # Countdown: 9 None
> ```

Answer (score -2):

Another solution:

```
for i in range(10):
    print "Countdown: %d\r" % i,
    time.sleep(1)
```