# How can I print a dynamic text in terminal using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, text, terminal

I want to print a constant message in the form of:

```
Time remaining: X Seconds
```

Where `X` will be a count-down number. But I don't want to have an output like:

```
Time remaining: 5 Seconds
Time remaining: 4 Seconds
Time remaining: 3 Seconds
Time remaining: 2 Seconds ...
```

I want only the number to change in the same text line. Is it possible using escape sequences or other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can!

Please refer to the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436240/python-2-7-carriage-return-countdown)

The code has been modified a little to look more like you want, and to use the more recent string formatting.

```
from time import sleep
import sys

for i in range(10):
    sys.stdout.write("\rTime remaining: {} Seconds".format(i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(1)
print '\n'
```

Comment: No, this is not what i'm asking ...
I want the same first line to mutate only at the position of the number. That's why I refered to it as "dynamic".

Answer (score 3):

You also have the `flush` parameter in the [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) method (I just discovered it as well):

```
from time import sleep

for i in range(10):
    print(f"\rTime remaining: {i} Seconds", end='', flush=True)
    sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add argument `end='\r'` in your `print` function.

```
import time

x = 10
width = str(len(str(x)))
while x > 0:
    print('Time remaining: {{:{:}}} seconds'.format(width).format(x), end='\r')
    x -= 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

You may also refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897359/output-to-the-same-line-overwriting-previous-output-python-2-5).

Comment: I copied your code but it printed as usual. The post was useful though.

Answer (score 1):

[I found this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122385/dynamic-terminal-printing-with-python)

And got it to work. The "stuff" is there to show that texted displayed before the count down is not getting 'clear'ed

```
import time
import sys

num = 5
print('stuff')

while(num >= 0):
    sys.stdout.write("\rTime remaining: {} Seconds".format(num))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
    num -= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set end= " " to remove newlines and add a carriage return '\r'

So the correct program which should work for you is:

```
n = 100
while n > 0:
    print('\rTime remaining: {} Seconds'.format(n), end=' ')
    n -= 1
    time.sleep(1)
print(' ')
```